# Yii: загрузка данных в модальное окно

Tags: ajax, php, yii

Есть:

- контролер собирающий данные и отправляющий их в вьюшку методом [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController/#renderPartial-detail)
- простая вьюшка
- слой(layout), при клике по ссылке отправляет запрос в контроллер, получает вьюшку с данными и выводит это в модальное окно.

Код вьюшки:

```
<?php
print $data;
?>
```

Код слоя:

```
<?
print CHtml::ajaxLink('<i class="icon-white icon-list-alt"></i>Объекты', $this->createUrl('site/regionstree'),
array('update' => '#regions_tree'),
array('onclick' => '$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;', 'title' => 'Список ваших объектов')
);
?>
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id' => 'mydialog',
    'options' => array(
        'title' => 'Список ваших объектов',
        'autoOpen' => FALSE,
        'modal' => true,
        'resizable' => false,
    ),
));
?>
<div id="regions_tree">
</div>
<?php
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
```

Не могу заставить данные загружаться в модальное окно:
Окно открывается, но запрос данных не происходит(проверял фаербагом)
Если в CHtml::ajaxLink убрать 'onclick', то запрос отправляется, но окно не открывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если убрать return false; в onclick?